# How to emulate the Publish action of Visual Studio in Azure pipeline on Linux self hosted Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have a project in c# we want to deploy using Azure Pipelines.

When I publish the project in Visual Studio 2019, I get the following structure:

```
bin\Release\net5.0\publish
 -> FolderA
    -> files
 -> runtimes
    -> files
 files
```

When I use the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task with , I get a different structure of files:

```
publishFolder
 -> runtimes
    -> files
 files
```

"Folder A" is missing, so launching the service fails.

this is my task in the pipeline:

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish API
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: AzureDevOps.Api/AzureDevOps.Api.csproj
        arguments: '--output  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/API  --configuration Release --self-contained true -r linux-x64'
        zipAfterPublish: false
        modifyOutputPath: true
```

we are building on a self-hosted Linux (Kubuntu) agent.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

include `FolderA` and have the **subfolders** present, set `self-contained` to true in your Azure Pipelines YAML task

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <OutputPath>bin\Release\net5.0\publish\FolderA</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

&

```yaml
arguments: '--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/API/FolderA --configuration Release --self-contained true -r linux-x64'
```

Comment: Hi,

Did the change to set self-contained to false, now I have no sub folders at all....